# OpenCV C++ feature detection keypoint color from image pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, sift, surf

I've looked into the Keypoint class but there are no attributes relative to the color of the keypoint.
Is there a way to store the color of each keypoint that has been detected with SURF or SIFT? 
I understand that Keypoint coordinates are float but is there a ways to get an approximate color for that Keypoint maybe based on the color of the pixel it's inside or the neighboring ones?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299409/how-to-get-the-image-pixel-at-real-locations-in-opencv

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that thread while searching. That solves my question.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't sure that was exactly what you were looking for. I'll go ahead and suggest it as a duplicate.